# Computing an infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos\frac{x}{2^n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, infinite-product

I would like to compute the infinite product
$\displaystyle f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2}\left({1+\cos\frac{x}{2^n}}\right)$ for a given real $x$.

Since the terms in the product are positive and smaller than $1$, the product is bounded by $0$ and decreases. Therefore the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$ is well defined.

I know that 
$\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos\frac{x}{2^n}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and I wonder if $f$ also has a simple analytical expression.

Thank you.

EDIT : Using the expression $\cos^2(x)=(1+\cos(2x)/2)$ I can reducethe first sum to the second and get
$f(x)=\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x \cos(x/2)}\right)^2$

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake, I edited.

Comment: Wolfram [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product+(1%2BCos%5Bx%2F2%5Ek%5D)%2F2) it's actually: $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+\cos \frac{x}{2^n} \right)=\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}$$ if we start with $n=0$, not $n=1$

Comment: Yes, thanks, I solved it by reducing to the known product (I have edited with the answer)

Comment: Well, I've already posted an answer, hope you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the well known product and square:

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos\frac{x}{2^n}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos^2\frac{x}{2^n}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$$

Now use the formula:

$$\cos^2 \frac{t}{2}=\frac{1}{2} (1+\cos t)$$

To get:

$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+\cos \frac{x}{2^n} \right)=\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}$$